# Java Simple framework with Coffeescript

Tags: java, coffeescript, simple-framework

Has anybody got experience in integrating Java Simple Framework with Coffeescript? I'm desperately in need of an example to compile Coffeescript in run-time. I'm thinking of wro4j but not sure how to integrate that with Java Simple Framework.

Comment: Do you mean JSF, which stands for Java Server Faces?

Comment: Sorry I really mean Simple framework http://www.simpleframework.org/

Comment: There is a wiki page describing how to integrate coffeeScript: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/EasyUseOfCoffeeScript . If you have problems with this or any other questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rhino javascript engine, here's a nice short tutorial:

http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/

And include this file (the coffeescript to javascript compiler, written in javascript):

http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js

Then use CoffeeScript.compile() to compile and then run your code. Would that work for your needs?